# Can "stile" mean another thing than steps over a fence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading a story called Ancient Lights, and I am not sure if the meaning is the one mentioned in the title:

> He had that instinct, and as a rule it served him well. “A mile or so
> due west along the sandy road till you come to a stile on the right;
> then across the fields. You’ll see the red house straight before you.”

As there is no mention of any fence or so, I am not sure if this cannot mean something else.

Comment: I don't think there are any other meanings for the word "stile".

Answer (score 6):

No, a [stile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stile) always means a little set of steps over a fence or wall. They come in [many shapes and types](https://www.google.com/search?q=stile&source=lnms&tbm=isch), but they're all basically the same type of thing.

[image: stile over wire fence]
[image: stile over stone wall]

This makes sense in context because a stile would be how someone could switch from walking along a road to walking across fields. In this story, the character describes going "along the sandy road" until reaching a "stile on the right" (on the right-hand side of the road; this would be a stile across the fence or wall that borders the road) and after that continuing "across the fields" (they must have got into the fields somehow from the road, which is where the stile comes into play).